# iOS Chart: How to set bar width to a fixed size?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I would like bar width equal to 30 pixels.

barData.barWidth let me change it but this is proportional to chart width and number of bars to display, which display a big bar on iPad for only one element.

Do you have an idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you check & tried my answer ?

Answer (score 16):

You Can not fix `BarSize` directly in **ios-charts** but you can change the default ratio width of the bar.

By default `barWidth` ratio is **0.85** so based on this it will cover 85% area of the chart if you have only 1 Bar on the chart and if you have 2 it will calculate the ratio based on Bar count so you can set approximate bar width with this property.

**Default value:**

```
/// **default**: 0.85
    open var barWidth = Double(0.85)
```

**You can set:**

```
let chartData = BarChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)

chartData.barWidth = Double(0.01)

chartData.barWidth = Double(0.10)

chartData.barWidth = Double(0.25)

chartData.barWidth = Double(0.30)

chartData.barWidth = Double(0.50)
```

like that you will achieve your fix width **between 0.01 to 1.00**.

Hope this will helps!

Comment: I am not able to see barWidth property in chartData ..from where did you get this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming chart width is fixed:

step 1: find the ratio for required width in scenario where there is only one element on x-axis (for me it was 0.05)

step 2: set the bar width to this ratio multiplied by element count on x-axis

`data.barWidth = 0.05 * Double(xArray.count)`

This will work because max width for a single bar is inversely proportional to number of elements on x-axis

For variable chart width you will need an additional factor for bar width correction: (original chart width/current chart width)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `chartView` to the `scrollView`, then set the `chartView.width`and `scrollView.contentsize`

```
width = values.count * fixedWidth 
chartView.width = width
```

and

```
scrollView.contentSize = {width,scrollView.height}
```